# Did any doctrine follow Zen Buddhism?

Tags: buddhism

My understanding of Zen Buddhism and it's place in Buddhist history is that it represents a philosophical and experiential end-point, a sort of conclusion to Buddhist thought.

I'm wondering if this view is correct? Did Zen Buddhism have significant influence on any threads of philosophy that came after it? Or was it ever built on into a new idea?

Comment: Zen (also known as Ch'an) is a school of the Mahayana branch of Buddhism, most often identified in the West with Japan. A good book is D. T. Suzuki's 'Asvagosha's Discourse on the Awakening of Faith in the Mahayana'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to distinguish two strains of Buddhist philosophy, that of Hinayana (Theravada), and Mahayana.

The original Pali canon doctrine, which is still held today by Theravadins, is an epistemological variant of direct realism. In the original Pali canon's Abhidharma, when you see the earth, you just see the earth for what it is; nothing less, nothing more. Absent are the topics of duality, non-duality, or Emptiness*. The emptiness (note the lowercase) indicates only the illusion of Self (ego) that one needs to extinguish to become an Arhat. Good and Evil are clear and distinct concepts for the practitioners of original Buddhist teaching. Theravadins are, therefore, moral realists about Good and Evil and the real world [1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/bps-essay_27.html). They merely reject the existence of Self (ego) as an illusion.

In the Mahayana doctrine, Nagarjuna's Madhyamaka school introduces us to the concepts of two truths: **conventional** and **ultimate**. Here's where we have either idealism (of Yogacara school), or a variant of indirect realism, at best. So, when we see the earth, say, Yogacarins tell us that we don't see what it really is, but we see a representation of earth that is tainted by our karmic seeds. Seeing earth, we experience merely conventional (human) reality. What really is out there, is the ultimate, non-dual reality (i.e. Emptiness). In ultimate reality, things are empty of their individual (dualistic) existence like a stone, as they are interconnected to each other by causes and effects. Thus, Mahayana Buddhists stretch the doctrine of Self beyond the simple lack of ego as it is in Theravada, proclaiming that all things lack Self-existence. That includes concepts as Good and Evil, and so forth (so they are "empty" of Self-existence). Mahayana is essentially a merger between Hinduist and Buddhist thought where ultimate reality is akin to the concept of [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman#Advaita_Vedanta), and conventional reality is akin to the Advaita Vedanta concept of [Maya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(religion)#Vedanta_school).

While Yogacara was mainly expressed by the Chan (or Zen) school of Buddhism, it was philosophically questioned and surpassed by Chandrakirti and Tibetan Vajrayana scholars. Chandrakirti and Tsongkapa (Gelug school), prominently rejected Yogacara in favour of Prasangika. Prasangika radically rejects the doctrine of two truths and based its tenets on [consequential syllogistic reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasa%E1%B9%85gika_according_to_Tsongkhapa#Consequential_syllogistic_reasoning) (it's quite beyond the scope of this post).

While the former Theravadin doctrine had little to no influence on Western philosophy, it cannot be said of Mahayana. Yogacara, in particular, was highly influential for Western German idealist philosophers like Arthur Schopenhauer who built their systems on Buddhist foundations. Schopenhauer's system, with its ethics, mirror Yogacara school to great extent. Additionally, there exist some parallels between Kant (phenomenal vs. noumenal realm) and the doctrine of two truths, and Chinese Yogacara scholars like Vasubandhu and Xuanzang. Those scholars were indeed of the Chinese Chan (Zen) tradition. Overall, among Zen Buddhists, Yogacara is the dominant philosophical position.

*- Capital *E* indicates the metaphysical doctrine of ultimate reality.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So if we restrict ourselves to looking *within* Buddhism has Mahayana/Zen remained basically unchanged to the present day?

Comment: @CanadianCoder more or less - yes, with small differences within different sects. But this is because it is a religion. They do have certain non-negotiable core dogmas based on scripture revelations. In the same spirit, Christian theology can only go as far as it historically went.

Comment: @CanadianCoder I'd like to add is that the main differences between Zen schools occur merely within the area of practise itself, not philosophy. For example, consider Soto Zen vs Rinzai Zen. They differ in that the Rinzai school concentrates on chants and koans, where Soto on meditation (Shinkatanaza). Those are the main kind of differences in Zen. Vajrayana, on the other hand, differs greatly both in terms of practice and philosophy; therefore they are considered a third separate vehicle (alongside Hinayana and Mahayana).

Answer (score 1):

It seems funny to me you would think that, given the many schools & styles found in [Chinese Zen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan_Buddhism), before even accounting for Japanese Korean & Vietnamese developments. Which version of Zen do you see as an endpoint? Beyond Nagarjuna's underpinning philosophy, synchretism with Chinese cultural values like intolerance of begging for food, and emphasising commonalities with Confucianism & Taoism like through focus on 'wu wei' (effortless action, a term originally from Confucianism), must be seen as formative & continuing impactor on Zen. It has not been static.

I would point to cultural traditions, like the Japanese tea ceremony, and especially Japanese aesthetic principles like wabi-sabi which has become well known, & explicitly seeks to manifest the Buddhist 'Three Marks Of Existence'. The tea ceremony & specifically Okakura Kakuzo's 1906 'The Book Of Tea' was formative for Heidegger on his central concept, 'dasein'.

Zen reached Tibet, survived for several centuries, & then ceased as a distinct tradition there. Many debates were recorded, & the Tibetan formulation of what the different vehicles to awakening are was explicitly set down with Zen in mind. So Zen was both incorporated in some ways, & reacted against in ways that still shape Tibetan thought. Is that building on?

The different branches of Zen, have generally merged lineages through students being recognised by multiple teachers of different lineages. Some classical schools left no lineage, but produced works influential on Zen thought. Where merging has not occurred there is generally a reason, like the Rinzai-Soto split was about whether funeral services would be given to non-Buddhists. Zen has adopted many aspects of Pureland thought, like chanting to & referencing Amithaba Buddha - Pureland has always been a simple practice for all people, while Zen focused on dedicated monastic practice & retreats. There has long been a push there to Zen to be more accessible, & provide rites for different people & circumstances (rites often being key to monastic income).

In China there is a movement to formally merge Zen & lineages of other schools, like by Fo Guang Shan in Taiwan, which exemplifies this.

Shaolin monastery mountain is where Bodhidharma meditated for 9 years. You may have heard of impacts on martial arts & Chinese culture from there.